# Debugging an ELF file

Tags: linux, debugging, reverse-engineering, remote-debugging, elf

I've got this EFL file which I need to debug/step-through. It's a reverse engineering competition. All I need to do is to find out the value of a register at a particular point in time and in a particular place. I used Hopper Disassembler to find out the address of interest.

Here's the problem. I don't know how to debug an ELF file. It's my first time debugging in a Linux environment. Learning how to execute the ELF file itself took me a while. I execute by using 
`ld-linux.so.2 ./[EFLFILE] [arguments]`

Is there a way I can atleast attach a debugger onto the proess? I can't even find it with the ps command. Also, I've heard that it's possible to have remote debugger; to have a debugger running on a windows machine and have the binary to be examined running on a linux.

Could anyone help me achieve just any of this?

Comment: You may use [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) to debug a program under linux

Answer (score 3):

Usually an ELF file can be executed as follows:

```
$ /path/to/elffile [arguments]
```

To debug it using [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) you can do:

```
$ gdb /path/to/elffile
```

Or passing arguments:

```
$ gdb --args /path/to/elffile arguments...
```

In your case:

```
$ gdb --args ./[EFLFILE] [arguments]
```

Then type `run` or simly `r` and press < Enter >.
Type `help` to get help on the gdb commands.

Note: if your program needs some external libs, before running it, you should define LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing on the folder containing those libs (`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/the/path/to/libs`)

Comment: No matter what I do, I can never execute the ELF file by just going
'$[filename]'

I keep getting the message "no command [filename] found"

When I try to use gdb that you suggested (the line at the "in your case"), I get a Permission denied, even after using sudo. I'm using the newest ubuntu.

Comment: I think it's because it's a 32 bit ELF on a 64 bit ubuntu installation. I'll a 32 bit system running and will try the same.

Comment: @hexinx if you get permission denied make sure your file has execution rights `$ chmod +x elffile`, however gdb won't work if you cannot run in standalone you binary

Comment: you can check what kind of binary (32/64bits) is your program by using `$ file elffile`